# Create a standardized installation package to install Visual Studio 2010 for multiple developers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What would be some ways of creating a standardized installation of Visual Studio 2010 which would include a set of add-ons and extensions?  This would be used to install VS2010 in a standard way for multiple developers.